# Azure: What is the relationship between vCPU and ACU?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

In Azure Function's Premium plan, I need to choose an App Service Plan and I chose the `Elastic Premium EP1`;  It says: `210 total ACU, 3.5 GB Memory, 1 vCPU`;

About the ACU:
ACU is currently standardized on a Small (Standard_A1) VM being 100 and all other SKUs then represent approximately how much faster that SKU can run a standard benchmark; For example, my dev VM: `Standard_D2s_v3` , has an ACU of 160 and below specifications:

```
vCPUs:  2
CPU Architecture:   x64
Memory: 8 GiB
Hyper-V Generations:    V1,V2
Azure Compute Units (ACUs):     160
```

I cannot understand this: my VM has 2 vCPUs and only an ACU of 160; meanwhile a single vCPU in Azure function's EP1 gives 210 total ACU.

Why?

Is the single 1 vCPU that Azure Function's EP1 is using a lot different from the 2 vCPUs that my dev VM is using?

How are they different?  Do they use different hardware under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [**Document.**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/virtual-machines/acu.md)

Azure ACU is used to compare performance across Azure SKU's. Then, all other SKUs generally indicate how much faster that SKU can complete a common benchmark. At the moment, ACU is standardised on a Small (Standard_A1) VM being 100. For different workloads the results may vary significantly.

In response to your inquiry, the Elastic Premium EP1 SKU has 1 vCPU, 3.5 GB Memory, and 210 total ACU. Your development VM, Standard_D2s_v3, has two virtual CPUs (vCPUs) and an ACU of 160. This is because:-

The ACUs boost performance by increasing CPU frequency using Intel® Turbo technology. And the degree of performance varies according to the size, workload, and active hosts of the VM.  As a result, there may not be much of a difference between the single virtual CPU in Azure Function's EP1 and the two virtual CPUs in your development VM. The ACU is a better approach to compare their performance because they use different hardware inside.

Also, As per the document, If the The Elastic Premium EPI plan has 210 ACU's then it falls under SKU's that support 195-210 ACU's.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  `The ACUs boost performance by increasing CPU frequency using Intel® Turbo technology. `  --- this is what I am looking for.   So while they are both called vCPU in Azure Function and VM, they are actually CPU chips with different frequencies.